# Where is php code of price table page in opencart 2x?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

i want to edit price table page in opencart but can not find php code of this madule.
parice table page in catergory , information and price table in opencart
can u help me?

Comment: Edit the file admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl

Comment: check this tpl but not code for price table . not price of product.

Comment: You mean database queries for product price?

Comment: No,i want to create or edit this in opencart maxshop 2.1

Comment: https://designsmaz.com/html-css3-responsive-pricing-table/

Comment: You want the page where the list of products according to category shows up? like this https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=25_28 ?